# How to present Settings view on button click (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

My `macOSApp` is a menu bar app, hence the app is never really 'in focus' so it's not immediately obvious that the user can use the `CMD + ,` shortcut to open the app's settings.
For this reason, I'd like to add a button option so the user can open settings via the menu bar too:

```
@main
struct macOSApp: App {
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        MenuView()
            .environmentObject(Authentication())
    }
    WindowGroup("LoginView") {
        LoginView()
            .environmentObject(Authentication())
    }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "macOSApp://LoginView"))
    Settings {
        SettingsView()
            .environmentObject(Authentication())
    }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "macOSApp://SettingsView"))
  }
}
```

I have added a `Settings` scene, which works perfectly if the user opens it up via the `CMD + ,` shortcut.  And I've added a `.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "macOSApp://SettingsView"))` modifier onto it so upon button click I can run:

```
if let url = URL(string: "UpSend://SettingsView") {
   openURL(url)
}
```

Which works for my login screen, but when it runs, it just takes the main view of the app and puts it in its own window, not showing the `Settings` screen.

I appreciate I'm not using a `WindowGroup` I'm using `Settings` so opening up the window might need something entirely different, I just don't know what?

Answer (score 3):

For macOS 13.0

```
if #available(macOS 13.0, *) {
    NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showSettingsWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
}
else {
    NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showPreferencesWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
}
```

Comment: I get error: "Cannot find 'NSApp' in scope"

Comment: Try: import AppKit

Answer (score 0):

Don’t include the “macOSApp://“ part in handlesExternalEvents. Try this:

```
Settings {
        SettingsView()
            .environmentObject(Authentication())
    }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "SettingsView"))
}
```

Comment: same thing sadly

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showPreferencesWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

From macOS 14 on, you can use the new SettingsLink

```
SettingsLink(
    label: {
        Text("Settings")
    }
)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settingslink